# Value not found when using :load in Spark's Scala REPL

Tags: scala, apache-spark, read-eval-print-loop

Any idea why Spark's REPL (Spark 2.0.0) would be throwing the following errors:

```
scala> :load ../StatsWithMissing.scala
Loading ../StatsWithMissing.scala...
import org.apache.spark.util.StatCounter
defined class NAStatCounter
<console>:22: error: illegal start of statement (no modifiers allowed here)
   override def toString: String =
   ^
<console>:26: error: not found: value stats
           "stats " + stats.toString + "NaN " + missing
<console>:26: error: not found: value missing
       "stats " + stats.toString + "NaN " + missing

<console>:1: error: eof expected but '}' found.
}
^
defined object NAStatCounter
warning: previously defined class NAStatCounter is not a companion to object     NAStatCounter.
Companions must be defined together; you may wish to use :paste mode for this.
<console>:27: error: value add is not a member of NAStatCounter
     def apply(x: Double) = new NAStatCounter().add(x)
```

When loading the following file :

```
import org.apache.spark.util.StatCounter

class NAStatCounter extends Serializable 
{
  val stats: StatCounter = new StatCounter()
  var missing: Long = 0

  def add(x: Double): NAStatCounter = 
  {
    if (java.lang.Double.isNaN(x))
      missing += 1
    else
      stats.merge(x)

    this
  }

  def merge(other: NAStatCounter): NAStatCounter =
  {
    stats.merge(other.stats)
    missing += other.missing
    this
  }

  override def toString: String = 
  {
    "stats " + stats.toString + "NaN " + missing
  }
}

object NAStatCounter extends Serializable 
{
  def apply(x: Double) = new NAStatCounter().add(x)
}
```

Using `:Load ../StatsWithMissing.scala` does not produce any errors, but when trying to create an NAStatCounter I get the following error:

```
scala> :paste ../StatsWithMissing.scala
Pasting file ../StatsWithMissing.scala...
import org.apache.spark.util.StatCounter
defined class NAStatCounter
defined object NAStatCounter

scala> val nas1 = NAStatCounter(10.0)
<console>:28: error: reference to NAStatCounter is ambiguous;
it is imported twice in the same scope by
import $line48$read.NAStatCounter
and import INSTANCE.NAStatCounter
       val nas1 = NAStatCounter(10.0)
                  ^
```

Answer (score 1):

You're not using K&R braces, and since the repl interprets line-by-line, the opening brace is not the body of the class.

Try `class NAStatCounter {`, i.e., with the brace on the same line.

Otherwise, `class C` is a complete definition by itself.

Comment: Switching to K&R yields a different error :  
import org.apache.spark.util.StatCounter
<console>:13: error: not found: type StatCounter
         val stats: StatCounter = new StatCounter()
<console>:13: error: not found: type StatCounter
         val stats: StatCounter = new StatCounter()
<console>:26: error: not found: type NAStatCounter
         def apply(x: Double) = new NAStatCounter().add(x)

Comment: Actually, using `:paste` fixes both the brace issue and defining the companions together. You may be hitting bugs with spark shell doing imports correctly. I'll try it out later; unless someone answers first.

Comment: Correct, :paste does fix both issues. At this point I am trying to understand why this is happening out of curiosity. Thank you.